# Suggestions about a platform for sharing projects and ideas

Tags: web-apps, project-management, cms

A customer asked us for build a web platform that allows users to *share ideas and projects to improve the environment*.
The main requirements are:

- Anyone can register an user account on the platform.
- Any user can create one or more ideas projects
- A project is composed by: Title,Abstract,Attached File with full
  description
- The project must be validated before its publish. The platform
  administrator validates the projects
- A published project can receive comments (both anonymous and
  registered)
- A published project can have Social likes

The customer has shown us [this site](http://www.chest-project.eu/) as a reference.

So, We are actually evaluating two ways to handle this project:

1. Build the platform from scratch.
2. Build the platform over another well-known platform, such as a CMS
   like Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla.

Has anyone faced a similar request? Is there a ready-to-use platform that can handle the above requirements?

Comment: I think the question should be divided. Point 2 is more suitable for [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Point 3 would be on topic here if you reword the question to emphasize that

Comment: @Timmy, I edited the question, I hope it's more appropriated.